# AWSCognito Verification Code delivery details getting nil during sign up

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are working on AWS Cognito for our iOS app. While during SignUp with mobile number not using email, i am getting success response and mobile number inserting in DB, but code delivery details getting as nil. Is there any way to get the verification code to mobile once sign up/ during sign up process.

Thanks.

1. Configuration completed
2. userPool?.signUp("+915555555555", password: "Kaa@1234", userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in

in above method getting success and code delivery details getting as nil

is there any alternative to send OTP